# HTML drop down doesn't work

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, padding, html

This is part of my code. I'm trying to work with drop down. I'm unable to  select the drop down items. If I removed the line `style="padding: 80px;"` at the last `<span>` element, it works well. But I need that line for alignment. This is [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3xBPL/1/)

```
<input type="text" name="city" maxlength=20 size=15/>
<span style="padding: 10px;"></span>
<select>
<option value="0" selected>Please Select</option>
<option value="tamilnadu">Tamilnadu</option>
<option value="kerala">Kerala</option>
<option value="karnataka">Karnataka</option>
</select> 
<span style="line-height:20px"> City </span>
<span style="padding: 80px;"> State/Province </span>
```

Can you please tell what is the problem in this code. Why `padding: 80px;` causes the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of `padding:80px` try giving `padding-left:80px`. Because the padding of the element overlapping the `<Select>`

http://jsfiddle.net/3xBPL/9/

Comment: can you please explain?

Comment: Becuase the padding of the element overlapping the `<Select>`

Answer (score 2):

You need to toggle with z-index.

See : http://jsfiddle.net/3xBPL/7/

```
<select style="z-index:999; position:absolute">
  <option value="0" selected>Please Select</option>
  <option value="tamilnadu">Tamilnadu</option>
  <option value="kerala">Kerala</option>
  <option value="karnataka">Karnataka</option>
</select> 

<span style="padding:80px; z-index:1;"> State/Province </span>
```

Reason : The span area is overlapping the select box

[image]

Comment: This would work, but the padding: 80px simply isn't needed in general.

Comment: Because the span will take up the space which will be right above the select box. Like a layer. So by using the z-index you can specify which one you would need to display above each other. See  :http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=829a561

Comment: In the above image, im hovering over the span that you have created and the span is placed above the select box and thats the reason why it cant be clicked. But towards the end you can click, this is because the span layer is not there. Using z-index, the span layer is made to fall behind the select box. To know more about z-index : http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/

Comment: z-index only works in specific contexts, and its just covering up a problem that can be solved with an easier method. Plus it requires elements to at least be position:relative, there's no reason to change the position, and its just going to throw everything else out of alignment.

Comment: Have you tried out a fiddle with `padding-left: 80px;` as you mentioned?'

Comment: Why i am using z-index css attribute both the span? it better to give `padding:0px 80px 80px 80px;`

Comment: @RoyMJ your question is right. but if i am using `padding-top:0px;` it will also showing perfect.

Comment: Okay.. `padding-left` is a solution, `z-index` is a solution, so maybe urs.. It always ends up with what works best for OP right? So just leave it to the person who asked the question n move on...:)..

Comment: z-index cause problems sometimes. `padding-left` is perfect. You explained clearly. thanks +1

Answer (score 1):

The padding:80px is definitely the problem.

Here's a screencap of Firebug: http://screencast.com/t/ISPMaYkyK1

Here's a JSFiddle of the solution: http://jsfiddle.net/jrconway3/4gVUn/

In the screenshot, you can see that the padding is causing your span to cover up the two input boxes. The span is an inline element, so some padding will work depending on the circumstances, but it still tries to line up with the other items. The vertical padding does not work because technically, all your current items are on the same line.

```
padding-left: 80px;
```

You can specify "padding-left" to ONLY set left padding. This will fix it so you can properly click on the items. Changing the z-index on different elements will set certain elements to have priority over others, making them appear "over" other elements. But that doesn't solve the root of the problem.

Others have already answered the question, but I already started writing so I decided I'd finish it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I think problem is in your span cause span start from the top. It overlapping the drowdown box.

Please checck [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3xBPL/12/)

I am editing this code -

```
<input type="text" name="city" maxlength=20 size=15/>
<span style="padding: 10px;"></span>
<select>
  <option value="0" selected>Please Select</option>
  <option value="tamilnadu">Tamilnadu</option>
  <option value="kerala">Kerala</option>
  <option value="karnataka">Karnataka</option>
</select> 
<br>
<span style="line-height:20px"> City </span>
 <!--<span style="padding:80px; border:1px #cccccc solid;"> State/Province </span> -->
<span style="padding:0px 80px 80px 80px;"> State/Province </span>
```

Please use -

```
padding:0px 80px 80px 80px;
```

Answer (score 0):

your code has overlap with your drop down

i put it in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3xBPL/11/)

also i give it a color to make it more visible , try to add some new `<br>` to see how it goes around

```
span{

    background-color:red;
}
```

Comment: dude, answer is based on the design, you give an answer without noticing that what he really want?!
can you based on his question tell me what he really want? he want the "State/Province" be in same line? or appear in next line, then i ask you why use span and not div!
and learn to read the question first then accuse others :
`Can you please tell what is the problem in this code. Why padding: 80px; causes the problem?`

Comment: hey cool dude. See my answer that accepted. Now what you can tell??? I did not blame you, just asked to give answer. Whatever you did is OK. But it cannot consider as an aswer. Sorry if you felt i was blaming you

Answer (score -1):

its because, with padding 80px, you will expand the span, and when you click dropdown, website say "the one that clicked is span, not dropdown, so dropdown wont viewed"

you can add border by doing this.. it will explain to you more clearly

```
<span style="padding:80px;border:1px solid black"> State/Province </span>
```

what do you expect with that span using padding:80px by the way?